# Android Studio (IntelliJ) and gradle, how do I add different versions of a dependency?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin

I need json-lib in my project.

I've added `json-lib` to my gradle dependencies, and this in turn has dependencies on various commons libraries.

This is the relevant section of my app/build.gradle (updated as per suggestion below from Médéric)

```
dependencies {
    compile 'commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1'
    compile 'net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:2.4:jdk15'
    compile 'commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.8.0'
    compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'
    compile 'commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1'
    compile 'net.sf.ezmorph:ezmorph:1.0.6'
```

However when I try to run my app I get the following:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added:org/apache/commons/collections/ArrayStack;
```

So the dependency is clashing with the libraries provided with Android Studio I presume.

I've tried to exclude the offending file like this:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/services/org.apache.commons.collections.ArrayStack'
```

But that doesn't work.

If I don't include the dependencies above, at runtime I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/commons/collections/map/ListOrderedMap;`
```

I'm running Android Studio 1.2.1.1 with Gradle version 2.2.1 and Android Plugin version 1.2.3

Added the repositories section of my build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    maven {
        url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven'
        artifactUrls 'http://mvnrepository.com'
    }
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
  }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'crashlytics'


android {
compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:10'
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

repositories {
        maven {
        url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven'
        artifactUrls 'http://mvnrepository.com'
    }
}
```

This is the code that causes the runtime error:

```
public static String toString(Object o) {
    try {
// the call to JSONObject.fromObject() below causes the runtime error. It is used to detect circular references
        JSONObject.fromObject(o);
        return objectGraphAsString(o, new StringBuffer()).toString();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        ...
    }
    return "";
}
```

And this is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/commons/collections/map/ListOrderedMap;
        at net.sf.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:1450)
        at net.sf.json.util.CycleDetectionStrategy.<clinit>(CycleDetectionStrategy.java:37)
        at net.sf.json.JsonConfig.<clinit>(JsonConfig.java:65)
        at net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:134)
```

UPDATED:

I'm now trying to use a different 3rd party library, in this case XStream, and I'm getting similar errors in a clashing dependency.

I can't be the first person who has needed to add a dependency like this. Is the Android build process really this broken?

Answer (score 1):

Have you try to use real dependency instead of a jar file ?

replace

```
compile files('libs/json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar')
```

by

```
compile 'net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:2.4:jdk15'
```

and do the same for other libs : gradle will manage to resolve recursive dependencies.

**Edit**

You need to exclude commons-collections which is common to multiple libraries. Try this

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile('net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:2.4:jdk15') {
        exclude group: 'commons-collections', module: 'commons-collections'
    }
    compile 'commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.8.0'
    compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'
    compile 'commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1'
    compile 'net.sf.ezmorph:ezmorph:1.0.6'
}
```

Comment: I tried that and get:
    `Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':lha'.
> Artifact 'json-lib.jar (net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:2.4)' not found.
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/json-lib/json-lib/2.4/json-lib-2.4.jar`

I see that the json lib is available here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.json-lib/json-lib/2.4

So added that to my build.gradle, updated above

Comment: try with classifier adding ':jdk15' at the and of the dependency. See my edited answer above. Hope it will help

Comment: Tried that (see updated entries in my question above), but I still get the original error:
`UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/commons/collections/ArrayStack;`

Comment: I just edited my answer with a dependency exclusion which can be built

Comment: If I exclude commons-collections, I get the runtime error detailed in my question above: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/commons/collections/map/ListOrderedMap;`

The particular json-lib class I'm using, `JSONObject` has a dependency on commons-collections.

Comment: You can now remove exclude 'META-INF/services/org.apache.commons.collections.ArrayStack'. Could you provide in your question a simple piece of code which raise this runtime error ?

Comment: OK, thanks, have excluded that, error still is there. Updating question now with code that causes runtime error.